# How we can change Jboss Fuse i.e Servicemix ASCII to Custom Display

Tags: java, jboss, esb, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix

How we can change below colored ServiceMix ASCII to any other color with My Name or any other thing.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your terminal can change colors, there is a setting where you can change them. There is no support in Karaf/ServiceMix to change colors per user. You need to do this on your terminal instead.

If you use Windows then there is such a setting also, if you click on the top left corner to access the terminal menu, where there is a color changer somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

See the custom branding section of the Karaf [manual](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/developers-guide/branding.html). 
There you'll find how to make it your own "name" / branding
and also the collors.

For example the following will give you the std. Karaf branding:

```
{

}
welcome = \
\u001B[36m        __ __                  ____      \u001B[0m\r\n\
\u001B[36m       / //_/____ __________ _/ __/      \u001B[0m\r\n\
\u001B[36m      / ,<  / __ `/ ___/ __ `/ /_        \u001B[0m\r\n\
\u001B[36m     / /| |/ /_/ / /  / /_/ / __/        \u001B[0m\r\n\
\u001B[36m    /_/ |_|\\__,_/_/   \\__,_/_/         \u001B[0m\r\n\
\r\n\
\u001B[1m  Apache Karaf\u001B[0m (4.0.0)\r\n\
\r\n\
Hit '\u001B[1m<tab>\u001B[0m' for a list of available commands\r\n\
   and '\u001B[1m[cmd] --help\u001B[0m' for help on a specific command.\r\n\
Hit '\u001B[1m<ctrl-d>\u001B[0m' or '\u001B[1mosgi:shutdown\u001B[0m' to        shutdown Karaf.\r\n

prompt = \u001B[1m${USER}@${APPLICATION}\u001B[0m>
{
}
```